# Are built-in react native components pure?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I've found in docs that `Flatlist`, `SectionList` are `PureComponents`. There isn't any information about other components (e.g `TouchableOpacity`). 
I want to find out which RN build-in component is pure to use `useCallback` when it's necessary.

If all other components aren't pure it isn't necessary to use `useCallback` in this example.

```js
export default App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const onPress = useCallback(() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1), [prevCount]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={onPress}
      >
        <Text>Press Here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** `Flatlist, SectionList, VirtualizedList` are `React.PureComponent` the rest components are `React.Component`.

## How to find which component is using PureComponent

You can check the source code of react-native components on Github either they are using PureComponent or normal Component.

You see TouchableOpacity of React-Native is extended with Component.

[TouchableOpacity source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js#L132)

[image]

But on the other hand, `you can see FlatList uses PureComponent`

[FlatList source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L280)

[image]

Also, you can see `SectionList` is used to `React.PureComponent`

[SectionList source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/SectionList.js#L177)

[image]

Here is the `Text component of React-Native` which `is not using React.PureComponent`.

[Text source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Text/Text.js#L88)

[image]

So the conclusion is by default every component extends with `React. Component` excluding those components which they have mentioned in the docs that they are using `React.PureComponent`.

## Where to use useCallback hook

So as you know, the Pure component is `used to optimizing rendering of a class component` so if you wanted to optimize functional component, then?

`you can use React.memo`

useCallback is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

`Learn about when to use memo or useCallback` read this interesting article.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: I understand what is `PureComponent ` and  `useCallback`. How to find out which RN build-in component is pure to use useCallback when it's necessary?

Comment: The mentioned components according to docs are using `PureComponent` by-default like `FlatList` etc and other ones are like `Image, Text, etc` are not using `PureComponent`  by-default because these list items can re-renders many times but there is a chance with these others components that (Image, Text, etc) they don't have a number of children so they don't requires to be `PureComponent` but if there is a case that your component has number of children and they are re-renders many times then you can do your own implementation.

Comment: I think the same, but I didn't find any proofs.

Comment: It's much better. Thank you. Could you remove parts about what is PureComponent and useCallback please?

Comment: It's been removed.

Comment: Link to the article by kentcdodds is very valuable.

Answer (score 5):

1. How to find out which components are `PureComponent` which are not?

   If you can not find the answer in the docs you can basically check react native source code. For example:

   - [Source code of FlatList](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L280) you can see it extend `React.PureComponent` ==> 
     it's Pure component
   - [Source code of TouchableOpacity](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/43c161c30aff2f5306d32c9994fefc9edae08f85/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js#L134) you can see it extend `React. Component` ==> 
     it's normal component
2. If all other components aren't pure it isn't necessary to use `useCallback`?

   It really depends:

   - React.memo is doing similar thing `React.PureComponent` but it for functional component. That mean if a React Native Component is implemented using React.memo, `useCallback` is helpful too.
   - If a React Native Component using shouldComponentUpdate to control the re-render and the props you pass from your component is involved in it, you `useCallback` is helpful too.
     Check [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-prevent-rerender-component) out you might find some sample code for undersatanding.

Comment: 2. That's right. I meant all kind of `Pure` (Component, custom shouldComponentUpdate, Memo)

Comment: 2. It's a good idea so I checked the source and didn't find a lot of React.memo and shouldComponentUpdate usage.

Comment: @StanislavMayorov Yeah. I think for for library which have been started long time ago, `PureComponent` might be the favour of choice. What I am trying to say is `React.memo` and `shouldComponentUpdate` will be affected by not  using  `useCallback`

Comment: They don't use React.memo and shouldComponentUpdate in RN source, maybe there are only several cases when it's used.